# android log cannot found

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

I cannot ndk-build my code in windows  . but it work in linux

andoird.mk

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

TARGET_PLATFORM := android-8 
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib –llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#$(call import-module)
```

hello.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOG_TAG "testhello"
#define LOGD(fmt, args...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, fmt, ##args)  

int hook_entry(char * a){
    LOGD("Hello ARM! %s pid:%d\n",a,getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

D:/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:357: warning: overriding commands for target `E:/yanshi/libhello//obj/local/armeabi'
D:/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:357: warning: ignoring old commands for target`E:/yanshi/libhello//obj/local/armeabi'

"Compile arm  : hello <= hello.c

SharedLibrary  : libhello.so

arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: –llog: No such file or directory

make: *** [E:/yanshi/libhello//obj/local/armeabi/libhello.so] Error 1

what's wrong with   llog  in windows 7 ?